# How to get two tables data into single column?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables emp_attendance and emp_leave.

emp_attendance:

```
id    date_in
200   2015-05-22
200   2015-05-23
```

emp_leave :

```
id    date_leave   status
200   2015-05-24    sick
```

How to get the below output?

```
 id     date          status
 200  2015-05-22
 200  2015-05-23
 200  2015-05-24       sick
```

I tried the below sql query. But i couldn't get the expected result.

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM emp_attendance e INNER JOIN emp_leave a ON e.id=a.eid  WHERE AND MONTH(e.date_in)='$monthSearch' AND YEAR(e.date_in)='$yearSearch'";

$employees = mysqli_query($connection,$query1);
    while ($i = mysqli_fetch_array($employees)) {
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>".$i['date_in']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$i['status']."</td>";
         echo "</tr>";
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) in mySQL to combine the data from two tables with similar structure.

```
(SELECT `id`, `date_in` AS `date`, '' AS `status` FROM `emp_attendance`)
UNION ALL
(SELECT `id`, `date_leave` AS `date`, `status` FROM `emp_leave`)
ORDER BY `date`
```

Then you can access the data in PHP:

```
$employees = mysqli_query($connection,$query1);
while ($i = mysqli_fetch_array($employees)) {
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>".$i['date']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$i['status']."</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir.